# Animating Prepend and Append with floats

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

This seems really straightforward but I'm having the worst time of it.  I have the following code working on the following divs.  Would love to animate the slider so that it looks like its gradually advancing forward, but when I use `.animate()` on `$(".person")` the items animate, and then the extra div is appended and everything ends up advancing more than I want it to.  My goal is to make the slider gradually advance the width of one of the images, which is 12.5%

**HTML:**

```
<div id="people-reel">
    <div class="person" id="alex"></div><!-- end #alex -->
    <div class="person" id="jenna"></div><!-- end #jenna -->
    <div class="person" id="martha"></div><!-- end #martha -->
    <div class="person" id="matt"></div><!-- end #matt -->
    <div class="person" id="mia"></div><!-- end #mia -->
    <div class="person" id="rich"></div><!-- end #rich -->
    <div class="person" id="ryan"></div><!-- end #ryan -->
    <div class="person" id="silvia"></div><!-- end #silvia -->
    <div class="person" id="tony"></div><!-- end #tony -->
</div><!-- end #people-reel -->
<div class="controller" id="left-controller"></div><!-- end #left-controller -->
<div class="controller" id="right-controller"></div><!-- end #left-controller -->
```

**CSS:**

```
#people-reel {
    width: 120%;
    left: -10%;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

#alex {background-image: url('img/our-team/alex.jpg');}
#jenna {background-image: url('img/our-team/jenna.jpg');}
#martha {background-image: url('img/our-team/martha.jpg');}
#matt {background-image: url('img/our-team/matt.jpg');}
#mia {background-image: url('img/our-team/mia.jpg');}
#rich {background-image: url('img/our-team/rich.jpg');}
#ryan {background-image: url('img/our-team/ryan.jpg');}
#silvia {background-image: url('img/our-team/silvia.jpg');}
#tony {background-image: url('img/our-team/tony.jpg');}

.person {
    height: 200px;
    width: 12.5%;
    background-image: url('img/our-team/mia.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function moveToLeft(){
    $("#left-controller").on("click", function(){       
        var firstElement = $(".person").first();
        $("#people-reel").append(firstElement);
    });
}
function moveToRight(){
    $("#right-controller").on("click", function(){      
        var firstElement = $(".person").last();
        $("#people-reel").prepend(firstElement);
    });
}

moveToLeft();
moveToRight();
```

Comment: when you append or prepend an item you need to compensate for it's width in your animation.. first I would suggest animating the container with the offset and not every .person... after the animation is done do the appending and the compensation for the width at the same time..

Comment: If you need help coding this.. put it in a http://jsfiddle.net, and I can help you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the pointer!  I just tried out your concept and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much to Webkit for the pointer!  The following code worked:

```
function moveToLeft(){
    $("#left-controller").on("click", function(){       
        var firstElement = $(".person").first();
        var inc = $("#people-reel").width() * 0.125;
        firstElement.animate({'width': "0"}, "fast");
        setTimeout(function(){$("#people-reel").append(firstElement);}, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){firstElement.animate({'width': inc}, 0);}, 1000);
    });
}
function moveToRight(){
    $("#right-controller").on("click", function(){      
        var lastElement = $(".person").last();
        var inc = $("#people-reel").width() * 0.125;
        lastElement.animate({'width': "0"}, "fast");
        setTimeout(function(){$("#people-reel").prepend(lastElement);}, 500);
        setTimeout(function(){lastElement.animate({'width': inc}, 0);}, 500);
    });
}

moveToLeft();
moveToRight();
```